# Is Proximal Gradient Descent exactly same with coordinate descent for LASSO

Tags: machine-learning

We have the lose function of `LASSO`:

$$L(\theta)=F(\theta) + \lambda||\theta||,\quad F(\theta) = \sum\limits_i(y^{(i)}-x^{(i)}\cdot\theta)^2.$$
And the minimal solution $\theta^*$ should satisfy following equations for all component $j:$

1. Proximal Gradient Descent:

$$\theta_j^* - \lambda \nabla_j F(\theta^*) = prox_{L_1}(\theta^*)_j = S_{\lambda}(\theta_j^*).$$

2. Coordinate descent:

$$\theta_j^{*} = \dfrac{1}{\sum\limits_i (x^i_j)^2}S_{\lambda}(\rho_j);\quad \rho_j=\sum\limits_{i}x_j^{(i)}\left(y^{(i)}-x^{(i)}_{-j}\cdot\theta^*_{-j}\right)$$

Here  soft thresholding function:
\begin{equation}
S_{\lambda}(x)= \quad \begin{cases}
x - \lambda & \textrm{if}\ x > \lambda\\
0 & \textrm{if}\ |x| \leq \lambda\\
x + \lambda & \textrm{if}\ x < -\lambda
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and the low index $-j$ means the vector without $j$-th component.

Two methods are very similar, but definitely they are different even we assume $\sum\limits_i (x^i_j)^2=1.$ I heard somewhere Proximal Gradient Descent and coordinate descent are exactly equivalent for LASSO.

Comment: The equations don't have the same complexity bound, I don't why they should be equivalent with lasso. See p.20: https://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/ofercoq/hdrFercoq.pdf

Comment: @NicolasMartin My answer is also not equivalent. They are totally two different method only both related to soft thresholding function.

Comment: It would require a mathematical demonstration to prove they are exactly equivalent in the lasso context. It requires good maths skills. Maybe you'll have better chances in a mathematical forum like https://math.stackexchange.com/